# See svn commit messages/comments when get sync source in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, synchronization

I work with SVN as source control and commit my codes on it through eclipse. when I go to below path, I see Update/Commit files in Synchronization Tab.

> Right Click On src of Project >Team > Sync With Repository

Now my question is, How I can see commit **messages/comments** in Synchronization Tab in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view comments on every commit to svn, you must do

> Right click on your file and go to team > show History

then on **History tab**, you see a table for revisions of this file that contains:

```
+----------+------+---------+--------+------------+
| Revision | Date | Changes | Author |   Comment  |
+----------+------+---------+--------+------------+
|          |      |         |        |            |
```